# Is it possible to get monster spawners in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if it was possible to get mob spawners in vanilla minecraft in creative mode. I'm playing on version 1.12.2.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the question is aimed at windows 10 edition or java?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command `/give @s mob_spawner`. This will only work if your world has cheats enabled; there's no other way to get a mob spawner in your inventory. (Using a tool enchanted with silk touch doesn't work, for example.)

The mob spawner will have a pig in it by default, but you can right click the block with a spawn egg (which you can find in the "Miscellaneous" section of the creative inventory) to change the mob that spawns in it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes but only with cheats

If you use the cheat `/give (playername) (itemid) (amount)`

You can then use https://minecraft.wiki/w/ to find the item ID of the item you want.
(sorry if this site goes down I don't know of any other way to find the item ID without going into the code)

For spawners the code is "52:" then a number defining what type of mob the spawner spawns.

Item IDs for all spawners

```
52:50 = Creeper  
52:51 = Skeleton  
52:52 = Spider  
52:53 = Giant  
52:54 = Zombie  
52:55 = Slime  
52:56 = Ghast  
52:57 = PigZombie  
52:58 = Enderman  
52:59 = CaveSpider  
52:60 = Silverfish  
52:61 = Blaze  
52:62 = Lavaslime (magma cube)  
52:63 = EnderDragon  
52:64 = WitherBoss  
52:65 = Bat  
52:66 = Witch  
52:90 = Pig  
52:91 = Sheep  
52:92 = Cow  
52:93 = Chicken  
52:94 = Squid  
52:95 = Wolf  
52:96 = MushroomCow  
52:97 = SnowMan  
52:98 = Ozelot  
52:99 = VillagerGolem  
52:100 = Horse
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Minecraft 1.12.2, the version the question specified, since item IDs don't get accepted into `/give` anymore.